# Insert row into table when select from another table does not have row to join on

Tags: php, mysql, database

We have a `messages` table that holds messages, and we have a `message_statuses` table that holds a users' individual interactions with each `message`

The `messages` table has a message that the user should see in the app. When they `GET` messages from our API we want to create a new row in the `messages_status` table that will track the users id and the read/seen status on that table so we can determine when to show them the message and weather or not to mark it as unseen and show a notification bubble.

When we select messages that the user should get, I know I can join on `message_id` like so

`SELECT * FROM messages AS a JOIN message_statuses AS b ON a.id = b.message_id;`

But if there is a new message added to the `messages` and we haven't added a new row to the `message_statuses` table to start tracking interaction for that user with that `message` then we want to add a new row so we can track open/read statuses as well as a deleted status.

Is there a way possibly using a sub query to not only select with that join but also insert a new row when we don't have a row in the `message_statuses` table?

I see this page here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html but I'm having some trouble understanding if this can work for us.

We're using PHP so I know I can work around it with some separate queries but I'm really wondering if we can get this to work in one query. I know I've seen insert on duplicate key with seems like it may work as well but I'm not terribly familiar with it.

**[UPDATE]**

I have tried adding this trigger before the sql gets run

```
$trigger = "CREATE TRIGGER insert_status_row AFTER SELECT ON text2bid_messages
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF selected.opened IS NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO text2bid_message_statuses (user_id, message_id) = ($user_id,selected.id);
   END IF;
 END";
mysql_query($trigger);
```

But this so far doesn't seem to be doing what we need, maybe I've added the trigger wrong? It kind of seems that maybe I can't make a trigger on select?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get *all* messages by using a `left join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages m LEFT JOIN
     message_statuses ms
     ON m.id = ms.message_id;
```

The columns from `message_status` will be `NULL`.

If you want to insert a record into `message_status` every time a new message is created, you can do so using an insert trigger.